# How to access a .properties file from my Java Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have deployed my java web service successfully using tomcat. This web service is accessing a configuration file (.Properties) I have placed the config.properties files in the following directory

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ProcurementWS1\WEB-INF\classes\MainPackagePr
```

ProcurmentWS1 is the name of the WAR file

this is how am trying to access it from my code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("procwsconfig.properties");
            properties.load(is);
```

And am getting a null pointer exception on load

can you tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Put your properties file inside project(inside WAR file).
2) Put it somewhere on classpath

Comment: Well am using eclipse and i included the file in the java build path and it did not work out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put it in src/config direct to config package in source , upon build it will go to /WEB-INF/classes/config/config.properties

and `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties");`

[image]

and then I created a Service Class in the same project which has a method.

```
public static InputStream getConfigAsInputStream(){
    return Service.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place it in somewhere on your class path and under any folder of your .java source files using :

```
 ResourceBundle bundle1 =         ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.witness.web.license.l10n.VersionsFileName");
    String fileName = bundle1.getString("11.1");
```

`com.witness.web.license.l10n` being your package