# FileNotFoundException when I have given the relative path to the properties file

Tags: java, fileinputstream, properties-file

I am trying to use a properties file to store my DB connection details. It worked when I created a Java application and gave the file name as it is since I placed the properties file in the project root folder.

However, I get a **FileNotFoundException** when I try this in my Web application. I created a res directory under the project node to hold the properties file. I then gave the path as "res/db.properties" but I get the exception. I also tried placing this file under the configuration files directory but still got the same exception.

Here is my code -

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;

    /**
     *
     * @author aj
     */
    public class getConfigValues {

        public String[] getPropValues() {
            String[] props = new String[4];

            try {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                String propFileName = "res/db.properties";

                InputStream input = null;

                input = new FileInputStream(propFileName);
                prop.load(input);

                props[0] = prop.getProperty("dbURL");
                props[1] = prop.getProperty("driverClass");
                props[2] = prop.getProperty("user");
                props[3] = prop.getProperty("password");

                return props;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ip) {

                props[0] = "not found";

                return props;
            } catch (IOException i) {
                props[0] = "IO";

                return props;

            }

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `res` a source folder? Try with `db.properties` directly instead.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that before posting. I added `res` as a source package folder and then ran the web app but still get the `FileNotFoundException`. Giving the file name directly didn't work either (That was my first setup - prop file in the project root).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As a web application you have no way of predicting the current working directory, so using a relative path will always be problematical;
- Depending upon how you web application is packaged, your property file may not even be a file system object. It may well be a resource buried in a .war file.

One reliable way for you to access this file is to build it into your web app's WEB-INF directory. You can then access it using [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/res/db.properties")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Alternatively, you could build it into the WEB-INF/classes directory and load it using [java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/res/db.properties")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Once a java process is launched, you cannot change its current directory. The "getRessource" founctions are the best way to search the files.

Comment: @Steve Noted - Thanks! I was able to solve my problem by following as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607357/how-to-access-a-properties-file-from-my-java-web-service) . But I still have my doubts. How is this any different from just putting my connection details in variables and using them? I will have to replace the WAR file and re-deploy if I follow this approach. My idea of using prop file was so that I could use this and effectively change DB connection details without having to re-deploy the whole application.

Comment: Now you're asking a better question! The normal strategy is to configure a DataSource in your application server, look that up (or inject it) into your application, and then use it to provide a database connection. This puts all the connection related information in the server config rather than your application.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the current directory is different when you run it as a web app... There is a System property that will tell you what the current directory is. Or you can use Class.getResource to use your classpath to find the res directory

Answer (score 0):

Your main mistake is trying to load a *resource* with file-related classes. Property files are resources to the application and thus should be placed *relatively* to this application.

"Relatively" means "in the class path".

In a standalone application, simply assure to mention the directory of those resources as part of the class path. In a web application, the directory `WEB-INF/classes` is already part of the application's class path.

Now comes the second part of the answer: How to load such resources? Simply: With a `ClassLoader`. Its responsibility is not only to load classes but also to load resources (such as property files).

Go with that (exception handling omitted):

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resourceUrl = loader.getResource("res/db.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
try(InputStream input = resourceUrl.openStream()) {
    properties.load(input);
}
String[] result = new String[4];
...
return result;
```